# How to reuse NextAuth Google OAuth authentication in a different server without making the user log to that server?

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I'm working on a NEXTJs app that authenticates with NextAuth, primarily via Google.
Now I need to implement a connection to another nodejs server with some websocket functionality. Is there a way I can verify the user on the other server without making them log in to the server within the app?

I know Google, and other providers, return access tokens. I was thinking of passing the token to the server and then somehow reauthenticating it with Google, since I don't know the secret they use to issue the token.